# Mysql Search LIKE with optional french characters

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I have names in the database like

```
tést
```

The Autocomplete works fine and all and if I seach for it like this:

```
WHERE title LIKE '%tèst%'
```

It works fine. But now i also want to find this entry if the user enters

```
test
```

(without the accent). In most cases its fine as autocomplete fixes the user up, but of course not always. How can I change the query so that the needle "test" also finds "tést" (other way round does not matter)?

Comment: Which collation are you using for title field?

Comment: utf8_general_ci, (im not french, this are just some names)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me.

I tested this on MySQL 5.5.8 using utf8 charset and utf8_general_ci collation.

I tried searching for `where title like '%tèst%'` and `where title like '%test%'`, and both queries returned both "tèst" and "test", which seems like what you want.

Does it not work like this for you?

```
mysql> create table french (
    -> title text
    -> ) default charset = utf8, default collate = utf8_general_ci;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.13 sec)

mysql> 
mysql> insert into french values ('tèst');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into french values ('test');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into french values ('toast');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> 
mysql> select * from french where title like '%tèst%';
+-------+
| title |
+-------+
| tèst  |
| test  |
+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from french where title like '%test%';
+-------+
| title |
+-------+
| tèst  |
| test  |
+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: This is what I expected to be the case when I suggested checking the collation.  It was a much older MySQL 4.x server I had handy to do my test on which also failed.

Comment: Ah ok it basically is supported, problem is something with my charsets somewhere different. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since MySQL search realization is very-very poor, there is no way to do it using just MySQL. By the way, you are not using full text searching (as mentioned in tags).

I would put this logic in your application, so it would find all the variants for those cases and append them to query.

A query you get at the end might look like this:

```
WHERE title LIKE '%tèst%' OR title LIKE '%test%'
```

Comment: this could get sick, its like 3 accents (`,´ and ^) and they can be on an a,e,o,u. This are like lots of combinations. I obv dont know what full-text-search means then :)

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to solve this with collation.  Collations in MySQL determine how characters are compared to each other.  The "e" and "è" difference is actually the example that MySQL uses in their documentation.  What are your current character set and collation set to?  I'm far from an expert on this, but may be able to help point you in the right direction still as to which collation to use.

Comment: This seems to go beyond my fairly basic (and maybe not quite right?) understanding of collations in mysql.  It seems like that collation should consider them equivalent by my understanding, but it apparently doesn't.  Tests on my own database also do not match the e to è.  Now I'm very curious about this.